# JavaScript: if statement; Running a check on the target of a touched element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, events

I'm in a React project, making it mobile friendly. I'm trying to make sure that before executing on some JavaScript powered className changes, that the element the user has just touched is NOT or a child of;

```html
<div class="aboutClassHidden">
```

To do this, I've got event listeners watching for where the user first touches, and reporting back the touched element through "event.touches[0].target".

However, my 'if statements' can't seem to grab onto the necessary elements to run the checks. My events are returning logs in the console as follows.[image] [image]

It's the 'target' and 'parentElement' properties is what I'm trying to identify. 
Right now, my if statement is structured as such;

```
const target = event.touches[0].target;
        if ( target || target.parentElement !== "div.aboutClassHidden") {
```

But so far... nothing has worked?

Any other suggestions? Thanks for your time pals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target.parentElement` is not *identical* to the string you provided, in fact it is an object with it's own set of properties and methods even if dev tools isn't exposing them to you.

`target.parentElement.className !== "aboutClassHidden"` is what you're after